# identifying values which would be truncated in an insert query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I was trying to insert some data into a table and I got the error message

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Now I know that this was due to trying to insert data which was too big for the column (in this case a VARCHAR(50) ), but it got me thinking about whether or not it was possible to:

a) see what specific values would be truncated (bearing in mind that this could happen for multiple columns), perhaps by giving an output of all of the rows which would be truncated?

b) if within a batch insert there is any way of seeing for each column which would be truncated the maximum input data value (so I could see if the data storage type actually needs to be changed or if it's only one or two cases which would not fit into the column?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no particularly satisfactory way of finding the problematic rows.

[This blog post has one solution.](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/danny/archive/2008/01/12/scuffling-with-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated.aspx) (`SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` and insert into a staging table then use `EXCEPT` against the source to find rows that did not import successfully)

Comment: I saw this, but the problem I found is that it doesn't make it obvious which column has been truncated (as i have numerous potentials) for each row which doesn't appear as the result of the except clause

Comment: Apart from @Dibstar 's fair point this is a great way to narrow it down. Might be worth mentioning that as a rule of thumb, if only half doing the job right could result in users seeing something misleading or bizarre it's better they see nothing at all. Best not use this in regular production unless either the exceptions are clearly flagged up to users or you're sure that the only realistic fail case creates 99% of users with no probs, 1% with non-critical probs.

In fact you could also set a `TRY CATCH` to rollback the whole thing if > n or n% errors.

Comment: @Adamantish I guess you could use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3248670/73226) to find the column. I see you already commented there too!

Comment: @Martin Smith Which one? No answer marked in that thread and the most upvoted one is a pain to do and will produce false positives too. As I commented in that post my fave is toss up between this one and Peter Kelly's one in this thread

Comment: @Adamantish - Peter Kelly's isn't much use on its own for the case that the source for an insert is a query rather than a base table. You would use `SELECT ... INTO` to create the table that you can then inspect via `sys.columns` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the maximum length of the columns in a table as follows

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTableName'
```

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is a built-in system View. This should help with your second question above.

Comment: I didn't know about this, should come in very handy :)

Comment: @Davin glad to help - you can upvote the answer if you like it and think it is useful :)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I have found is by selecting only the structure into a new table (SELECT INTO FROM WHERE 1 = 0) and comparing the columns types and lengths.[Full answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547592/13354011#13354011)

Answer (score 0):

If your using fairly simple types you can try

```
select datalength(mycolumn) from mytable where myid = 1
```

Comment: If you don't add a where clause to limit the rows, you'll get back 1 result for every row... (This is using sql-server... I'm not sure this will work for every DB.)